# how to add return url to paypal's javascript/rest express checkout simple intergration

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have paypals simple express checkout javascript  and I have a problem while testing it, I can not seem to fiqure out how to add a return url to the code below.

under the paypal developer sites apps & credentials, I have created a REST API app and added a return url there, but this does not seem to work with the simple javascript Express Checkout integration as listed below.

Can I simply pass in return and cancel urls or does the Basic client intergration not allow this??

sorry to ask a stupid question , it just palpays docs are not that good at all and looking threw google there lots of different options to do the same basic things

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>

// Render the PayPal button

paypal.Button.render({
    // Set your environment

    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

    // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
    // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

    client: {
        sandbox: 'sandbox',
        production: 'production'
    },
    // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

    payment: function () {

        // Make a client-side call to the REST api to create the payment

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {total: '10.99', currency: 'USD'}
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

    commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

        // Execute the payment

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
            // Show a success page to the buyer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: are you trying to run this locally?  I believe that you are making a call to Paypal , then they are calling the url you provided which has to be a real domain name with registered DNS

Comment: this is running live on a website that I am currently working on - everthing is working ok, its just I can not seem to get the return url working, or fiqure out how to add it in like https://example.com/paypal-success

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this widget as it is limited and hell lot buggy. But I think you would redirect by doing it within the `onAuthorize` callback handler.

```
paypal.Button.render({
    // etc...
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
            // redirect to success page
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // redirect to error page
        });
    }
}, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: i was think the same thing, you would think the basic intergration would be easy, but on testing on various browsers it works once then it doesn't, it shows different css styles on the popup light box, I will to ditch this and try the full rest api intergration in php